# Class with large number of properties

Tags: c#, model

I have a class which will have a huge number of properties (30 to 50). A huge numnber of these properties will be read only on the client. Is it a good practice to have one class with lots of properties or have smaller classes and use them as properties in parent class?

Note that objects of this class will be sent to client in JSON format and having one class with lots of properties will make the message a little smaller.

Comment: Could you provide more context on this? IE, is this being used in a WebAPI or a queueing system?

Comment: That's a bit like asking if a car needs a large number of nuts and bolts.

Answer (score 6):

In theory, it is better to have smaller classes when a logical grouping of the properties is possible. However, there are a number of cases where the cost of refactoring the class into smaller ones does not outweigh the benefits. Some possible reasons:

- refactoring will violate backwards compatibility of existing code, and refactoring all this code does not seem worth the hassle, or is not even possible since it is not under your control
- the classes structure shall reflect an existing data model or API in a 1:1 manner, where this model or API is not under your control
- the class works only as a "data transfer object", with no business logic in it, and there will be almost no code which is going to benefit from the better structure (but beware, you should be mostly sure that this is not going to change in the next version of your program)
- you expect a serious (and measurable) performance impact by using smaller classes
- one cannot easily use combined data types or references to other types in this specific class for some technical reason, so you are bound to the usage of primitive types

So when one of reasons above apply, you might be better off with those "30 to 50" properties. If none applies, I would heavily recommend to refactor to smaller classes.

Comment: Well put. Your 3rd point applies here and 4th too (just a little bit; I'll explain). Users are used to VBA forms. Now that they are moving to web every wait will seem like eternity. Hence, I want to keep performance as close as possible to existing app. Now, parsing hierarchical JSON will be little slower compared to flat structure. So, I would choose single class. Sounds reasonable to me at this point. Business logic is written in a way that it is very easy split classes into smaller ones if needed in future.

Comment: @danish: if the smaller classes only lead to a little bit more overhead in JSON parsing, I would not expect this to give you any measureable loss of performance. However, if this leads to more network roundtrips, then it might have a noteable impact.

Comment: Also large classes with lots of properties are cumbersome to test as setup becomes tedious.  Smaller is usually better with the exceptions mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what kind of properties and how they logically fit together. If they logically belong to the same object, then go ahead, there is no reason to split them up. If they logically belong on different sub-classes then to this.

The message overhead of having different sub-classes should not be a concern though. The overhead will be negligible unless you have a vast amount of traffic or really high performance requirements, in which case you should use a specialized protocol.

Comment: The dilemma is that they can be grouped logically. However there does not seem to be a need to do so as there is only one view where we see them. They come from a different (master) application so we will never edit/update them. I think I would go with one class. Thanks for response.

Answer (score 1):

You are pondering how to arrange all these properties, but should this data even be arranged in "properties"?

You say that most of these properties will only be used on the client side, so I assume your server is reading these properties from some database into the object, and passing them to the client as is. The server acts as a pipe - it's "awareness" to the structure of the data it pipes should be limited. If the pipe is aware of the structure of the data it pipes, it becomes one more place that depends on that structure - and that dependency does not provide much value.

Instead of properties, I suggest you use a dictionary or some other dynamic data structure - one that the code that deals with it does not need to be aware of the actual structure it holds. That way the server code does not need to care about how many properties there are and how their hierarchy is organized.

Keep in mind that:

- These few properties that you do need to use in the server should remain properties. They can either be concrete properties that get merge into the JSON, or they can be accessors that read/write from the dictionary.
- The client still needs to use these properties, so it may make sense to re-organize them for the client. Same for the database.

### With that being said...

Even if the server only pipes the data, sometimes you want to validate it. For that you can use a schema. You can use something like [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/), but there are also some libraries use classes as the schema and use reflection to read that. If you use such library, you'll need to write a class with all these fields as properties - but my answer still holds! Make sure you treat these classes as schemas, not as actual OOP classes. You don't write these classes for encapsulation - you write them as an alternative to writing a JSON schema in JSON. You don't need to apply the full blown OOP methodology on them just because they are classes.

Answer (score 0):

As the other already mentioned, the mere fact that you have "a lot" of properties is not a good reason to spread them over multiple classes. You may however want to categorize your properties and apply a hierarchy. This will make it easier to the receiver/user of the object to find the properties he needs, it would make the class easier to get your head around. So instead of Width, Height, Color, Fabric you would have Dimensions.Width, Dimensions.Height, Skin.Color and Skin.Fabric.

If message size really matters, resort to compression on the message level rather than screwing up your model.

Answer (score 0):

I would base this on the meeting of two factors:

1. Can any of the data be logically grouped? You mentioned in a comment they could.
2. Are there groupings of data in #1 that have a tendency to be empty?

For example, take a simple retail product management system. Several fields could be grouped together to represent the amount of product in inventory: warehouse, bin number, date put into inventory/age if perishable, number in stock, purchase price, etc. No inventory for this item wouldn't pull anything, so in that case there's less data.